# PHP MySQL File upload script not working

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am using the following script on a site and it works perfectly - following asking a questing on here. I have now tried to put this into another site and it is giving me the error Mysql error: No database selected any ideas? your help would be really appreciated I am quite new to this stuff. I know the script isn't the best from a security stand point - I am working on this!

```
<?php 

 require_once('../Connections/BrightLights.php');

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "images/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 
 $name=$_POST['name']; 
 $caption=$_POST['caption']; 
 $live=$_POST['live']; 
 $photo=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 




 //Writes the information to the database 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `gallery` VALUES ('', '$name', '$caption', '$photo', '$live')") ;  
    if( mysql_errno() != 0){
     // mysql error
     // note: message like this should never appear to user, should be only stored in log
     echo "Mysql error: " . htmlspecialchars( mysql_error());
     die();
}

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Well... have you selected a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "No database selected" error typically shows itself when you forgot to select a database with `mysql_select_db()` and called `mysql_query()`

Comment: Ok, thank you for your comment, how would I implement that into my above code. I have the same code being used on another site and it works fine.

Comment: I would need to see the code in the `BrightLights.php` file to check what makes it work on one site and not on the other. To make your current code work you can just add `mysql_select_db('your_database_name');` after the require.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I added mysql_select_db('your_database_name'); and it now works perfectly.

Comment: Just want to know why you selected the other answer if you asked me how to implement it? Doesn't seem logic to me?

Comment: My Apologies, I thought I selected both but it turns out you cant do that! - I have changed it now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Before u query the database u must first connect and select the database, then u can query it. Use this:

```
mysql_connect(hostname, username, password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(database_name);
```